# Image scales with column? Wordpress / HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

So, I'm new to Wordpress (.org). I basicially tried to put a picture next to a text, pretty basic. It covers the whole screen width and they are in each a column (50% text, 50% picture) . It ended up looking something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys7cq.png)

But as soon as I scale my browser (just to test different screen size) it ends up looking something like this:
The text starts to "overflows" and the picture is getting smaller (retaining their original ratio, but not their size)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNHJs.png)

I basicially want that the picture always stays the same height as the text like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NHRi.png)

This is how it currently is in Wordpress:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwZMy.png)

I tried to change and add stuff like height: 100% or something, but yea, it didn't change anything. I'm using the neve free theme too, if this affects anything.

Comment: Instead of an `Image` block you can use a `Cover` block with the image in the background. The image may be cropped as the window resizes, but the height will be the same as the text column next to it

Comment: Tried it out now, I don't mind the cropping, but the height still changes. Or more like, the text still overflows. Do I need to adjust something for the text too?